# Who Betrayed Fallow Core?

Tags: vorkosigan-saga

In Lois McMaster Bujold’s “*The Borders of Infinity*”, there is the following passage:

> "Was—was he injured when Fallow Core was overrun?" asked Miles. "Head injury?"
>   Oliver shook his head. "Fallow Core wasn't stormed, boy."
>   "But it fell on October 6th, it was reported, and—"
>   "It fell on October 5th. Fallow Core was betrayed." Oliver turned and walked away before his stiffened face could betray any emotion.
>   Miles knelt in the mud and let his breath trickle out slowly.

What was the significance of this revelation?

Comment: Part of the significance was merely that the prisoners were more disheartened and incohesive than if they had been defeated by military force alone (making Miles later job of reforming them into an army more challenging). It also played into Miles' use of Pitt as a scapegoat (and probably into the nearly fatal flaw in that action).

Answer (score 5):

The real question is not "Who betrayed Fallow Core?" but "What was the significance of this revelation?" (namely that Fallow Core was never stromed, but betrayed)

Essentially, Paul A. Clayton's comment is the answer. But to turn a simple comment into a full answer, let us go back. The common understanding of the situation, outside the camp, on Marilac, Barrayar and elsewhere (except of course on Cetaganda), is what Miles was thinking earlier

> But by this time Tremont and his troops had lost communication. So they held, waiting, and hoping. Eventually resources were reduced to hope and rocks. Rocks were versatile; they could either be boiled for soup or thrown at the enemy. At last Fallow Core was taken. Not surrendered. Taken.
> Guy Tremont. Miles wanted very much to meet Guy Tremont.

But now Miles realises this is a lie. Fallow Core was never taken. Granted, as Paul A. Clayton's commented, they are more disheartened than if they had been defeated, and harder to be reformed into an army. Miles must take this into account. But on the other hand, they are also more bitter. A soldier who has been loyally defeated by a superior force can accept defeat. A betrayed soldier will want his honour back, and if given a second chance, will fight with a revenge. Unless he is so broken that even if the second chance comes, he is unable to take it. And this is the whole point of the Dagoola IV camp. To break them once and for all.

And Miles makes it very clear a little bit later

> You are all here because you were Marilac's best and brightest, the hardest fighters, the strongest, baddest, most dangerous. The ones any potential resisters to the occupation would look to for leadership. It's the Cetagandans' plan to break you, and then return you to your world like little innoculated infections, counseling surrender to your people.
> "When this is killed"—he touched her forehead, oh so lightly—"then the Cetagandans have nothing more to fear from this"—one finger on her bicep—"and you will all go free. To a world whose horizon will encircle you just like this dome, and just as inescapably. The war's not over. You are here because the Cetagandans are still waiting for the surrender of Fallow Core."

So the massive escape, and subsequent return to Marilac of the defenders of Fallow Core, still embittered by the betrayal and not yet broken by their captivity will be just what Marilac needs to expel the Cetagandans eventually, as does happen a bit later.